# map json with AngularHttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

After updating my project to use the `HttpClient` module instead of the `Http` module, the following no longer works.

The problem is `Property json does not exist on type object`. I do need to get the `items` property. How can I achieve this?

```js
private loadLatestVideosForChannelId( channelId: string ): Promise<any[]> {

    // load videos from youtube-data-api
    let videos = this.http.get( 
            'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search' + 
            '?key=' + this.apiKey + 
            '&channelId=' + channelId + 
            '&part=snippet,id' + 
            '&order=date' + 
            '&type=video' +
            '&maxResults=3'
        )    
        .pipe(
            // if success
            map( res => {
                return res.json()['items'];    // the problem
            }),
            // if error
            catchError( (err) => {
                console.log( "YouTube API Error > Cannot get videos for this channel :(" )
                return null;
            }),
            take(1) 
        )
        .toPromise() as Promise<any[]>;

    return videos;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use .json() with **`HttpClient`** as the response itself already a json. change it as follows,

```
  this.http.get( 
            'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search' + 
            '?key=' + this.apiKey + 
            '&channelId=' + channelId + 
            '&part=snippet,id' + 
            '&order=date' + 
            '&type=video' +
            '&maxResults=3'
  )    
  .pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      return res['items'];
    })
  )
```

;